# Recover an HP recovery partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a (semi)-dead hard drive with an HP recovery partition on it.

My goal is to:

1. Buy a new hard drive
2. Copy the recovery partition to a drive (`dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=~/recovery.bak`)
3. Make a new partition of 12000 mb with Windows 7
4. Copy back recovery partition to the new drive (`dd if=~/recovery.bak of=/dev/sdb1`)

Then press <kbd>f11</kbd> when the laptop boots. However, this doesn’t work. Any idea why?

I suspect the <kbd>f11</kbd> doesn’t work because the laptop tries to boot the laptop, because my partition is the primary partition of the drive.

Does anyone have any experience dealing with stuff like this?

Comment: Can you try by plugging a USB keyboard in your laptop? Then, press F11. Parles-tu francais aussi?

Answer (score 3):

I’ve successfully done things like what you describe. When I do this, I boot up off of a Linux USB drive (Slax Linux is easy for this) so that I don't have the disk drives being used by the OS while I do my work. Then I would use `fdisk` or `parted` or `gparted` to partition the new disk.  Best and easiest is to have the same partitioning on both disk drives.

Once partitioning is done, you can dd from a partition on one drive to a partition on the other drive (e.g. `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1`).  You can use `fdisk` to set the partition to “active.”  In many cases, it’s easier to copy the entire drive first (e.g. `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`) and then use `gparted` or other tool to resize or move partitions (if needed).

In your case you could try the complete disk copy, and if/when it fails, follow up by copying just the partition(s) you are really interested in.